How to convert a combinatorial optimization problem into a problem hamiltonian
I want to ask how I can convert any combinatorial optimization problem into a Problem Hamiltonian, since such a conversion is needed in order to solve an optimization problem on quantum hardware (e.g. IBM's using Qiskit).
Or is there any way where I can load an LP file and then convert it into problem Hamiltonian?

Qiskit Optimization has a QuadraticProgram object that can read_from_lp_file and can then be converted to_ising Hamiltonian. This LP file reading does need CPLEX installed, as the docs note, but if you are using LP files I imagine you have that. The docs also have installation info, tutorials, the API ref etc.

This video tutorial is a very good starting point to the subject.
Then you can go through the paper "Ising formulations of many NP problems" by Lucas for more advanced mappings.

Thanks for your answer. But isn't it difficult to convert a problem into Hamiltonian with this approach. I means if an optimization problem has 1000s of variable then how to do that?
I found an example here in qiskit documentation - https://learning.quantum.ibm.com/tutorial/quantum-approximate-optimization-algorithm
Here they uses SparsePauliOp.from_list() function to convert Problem to Hamiltonian operator. But I don't know how to do that for knapsack problem.

The tutorial uses SparsePauliOp.from_list(). But how to know the list (i.e., the Pauli strings $IIIZZ, IIZIZ, IZIIZ, ZIIIZ$)? This tutorial does not provide enough details about how to build them. All what you find is the statement: "For this simple example, the operator is a linear combination of terms with Z operators on nodes connected by an edge"

You can convert pyomo (an open-source Python library for defining and solving classical optimization problems) problems to Hamiltonian problems using Classiq. Check this user guide to see how to do it. You also have a notebook teaching it here.
In the Git Public repo it is in https://github.com/Classiq/classiq-library/tree/main/applications/optimization
Generally speaking, once you define a Pyomo ConcreteModel (contains objective function and constraints), you can create a qmod based on it using construct_combinatorial_optimization_model which is a shortcut for explicitly writing the entire model. It calculates the Hamiltonian for you, builds a proper ansatz, and defines the QAOA for this problem.
So for example:
import pandas as pd
import pyomo.environ as pyo

from classiq import (
    construct_combinatorial_optimization_model,
    execute,
    show,
    synthesize,
)
from classiq.applications.combinatorial_optimization import OptimizerConfig, QAOAConfig

# Application object definitions and fields
application_object = pyo.ConcreteModel()

application_object.x = pyo.Var(
    [1, 2],  # variables names
    domain=pyo.NonNegativeIntegers,  # variables type
    bounds=(0, 3),  # variables range
)

application_object.cost = pyo.Objective(
    expr=3 * application_object.x[1] + 2 * application_object.x[2]
)

application_object.constraint = pyo.Constraint(
    expr=3 * application_object.x[1] + application_object.x[2] >= 2
)

application_object.pprint()

# going quantum - QAOA preferences
qaoa_config = QAOAConfig(num_layers=1)  # QAOA sub-circuit number of repetitions

# defining the model
model = construct_combinatorial_optimization_model(
    pyo_model=application_level_object,
    qaoa_config=qaoa_config,
)

# synthesizing a quantum circuit
qprog = synthesize(model)

# executing the circuit to solve the optimzation problem:
res = execute(qprog).result()

# post-processing the results:
from classiq.applications.combinatorial_optimization import (
    get_optimization_solution_from_pyo,
)

solution = get_optimization_solution_from_pyo(
    application_level_object,
    vqe_result=res[0].value,
    penalty_energy=qaoa_config.penalty_energy,
)
optimization_result = pd.DataFrame.from_records(solution)
optimization_result.sort_values(by="cost", ascending=True).head(5)
idx = optimization_result.cost.idxmin()
print(
    "x =", optimization_result.solution[idx], ", cost =", optimization_result.cost[idx]
)

# view and analyze the quantum circuit:
show(qprog)

Will give this circuit in platform.classiq.io:

And this solution
x = [1, 0] , cost = 2.9999999999999964

If you need the qiskit circuit object of, use this command to get the QASM:
QuantumProgram.parse_raw(qprog).transpiled_circuit.qasm

And convert it with the answer here
In the code I attached, you can also see the execution, and you can choose from the list of backends (all that are in IBM, Azure, AWS, NVIDIA GPU Simulator cloud)
Disclaimer - I am an engineer at Classiq
